# Swift 3 Firebase - Return All Users That Have An ID From An Array of IDs

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say in the front end I have an array of user IDs, pulled from another data source, I.E.:

```
let userIdArray = ["123456", "123457", "123458", "123459"]
```

And I need to query my Firebase database, returning all users that have one of the IDs in that array. How would I go about doing this? Do I have to create a new query for each ID? That would potentially be overly taxing, as the number of users in the array could be as many as 20-30 IDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will loop through ever userID at the fastest way, since it does not wait until 1 download has finished. I created a dispatch group and I enter the group before downloading the data, and leave the group when the data is finished downloading. After that, group.notify will notify you when the loop is finished.

```
func getUserIds() {

let userIdArray = ["123456", "123457", "123458", "123459"]
let group = DispatchGroup()

for singleUser in userIdArray{
group.enter()
    ref.child("insertpath/\(singleUser)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
  // Get user value
  let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
  group.leave()
  }) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
  group.leave()
     }
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {
print("loop finished")
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I was looking for dispatch, I read about it earlier today, got sidetracked, and lost it. Thanks!

Comment: @ErickMaynard yea some answer about dispatching looks very hard, this example makes it looks easy :) good luck